# Short film where man repeats a few minutes of his life in a loop

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, short-film

I remember seeing, years ago, a short film about a guy who gets stuck in a time loop and is forced to relive the same few minutes of his life over and over.

In one iteration, he talks to his smart aleck secretary. In another, he meets a woman in the park. He uses each iteration to find out more about what's going on. I think he even finds the scientist responsible for his problems. Eventually, he goes nuts and I think he kills himself.

What short film was this?

Comment: None of the items in http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/GroundhogDayLoop (Warning! TV Tropes link!) sound like a match, but in case one might spark a memory...

Comment: There are a few more in the Wikipedia article on time loops:
 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_films_featuring_time_loops

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The 1990 film, *[12:01 PM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/12:01_PM_(1990_film))* involves a man stuck in an hour-long time loop who confronts the scientist responsible, confronts his secretary, and tries to exit the loop by shooting himself. There was a 1993 remake, *[12:01](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/12:01_(1993_film))* involving a 24 hour time loop. They're both based on a short story, *[12:01 PM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/12:01_PM)* by Richard A. Lupoff.

You can view both versions below (no guarantees that the links will stay up):

**12:01 PM**

**12:01**

Comment: 12:01 PM. That's it!

Comment: That film's been looping in my head for years! :-)